What does "that" in "that consistent" refer to?
With his legs crossed, Robert and Jean, who is naked, are
sitting in separate chairs in a room:

Robert: You asked me to come. And I'm glad I did. But I can't see you
again.
Jean: But what if I need you? You said you would always answer. Not a
word?

Then the scene changes to Katherine sitting in the background,
Robert appearing before the committee, and answering Robb’s
questions one by one.

ROBB: Did you think that consistent with good security?
Robert: As a matter of fact, it was.

What does "that" in "that consistent" refer to?

I’m voting to close this question because it is about understanding the English language, and the occurrence in this film is incidental. Please try asking this on English Language Learners.
